# Python tkinter, cant find button in dictionary with .get()

Tags: python, tkinter

So when using .get() on a dictionary where the key is a name of a chess square e.g. "a1" and the value is a tkinter button e.g. .!button1 it doesnt work.

[image]

heres my code

heres my log

[image]

I code dict[key] and get a reponce
but dict.get(dict[key]) does nothing

it also doesn't work if i split the .get into a variable

[image]

fyi

Comment: `dict.get(dict[key])` makes no sense - `dict[key]` returns a value from the dict, but `dict.get()` wants a key.  Those are normally two completely separate sets of objects, in fact they're often two entirely different types of objects.  What were you expecting this line of code to do?  Do you simply want `dict.get(key)`?

Comment: i want to get the dictionary key from the value. I thought .get() did this

Comment: so is dict.get() the same as dict[key]. how do i get the key from a value

Comment: Dictionaries have no built-in ability to get the key from the value; `.get()` is just a way of looking up a value via a key, that doesn't generate an error if the key isn't found.  You'd either need to loop through all the key/value pairs looking for the specific value, or maintain a second dict with the keys & values reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the dictionary key from the value, I thought `.get()` did this, but it didn't.

The right way to do this:

```
for key, value in Dict.items():
    if value == "whatever you want the value to be":
        return key
```